# getting 502.3 errors due to large response in asp.net core 1.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, iis-express

running a MVC with asp.net core version 1.1 that can sometimes get a large number of records back (>10K). When it does I get a 502.3 http error from the server. This happens both with IIS express and the Azure application service.

Something in the web server is blocking the response, I've looked but I don't see where I might be able to set some configuration settings. I'm especially lost since there is no longer a web.config file.

will someone point out to me what setting I need to change and where I have to make this change?

I believe this is an IIS timeout of some sort but I'm at a lose as to where and how to set it now that the web.config file is no more.

Comment: What steps have you taken to troubleshoot? What does "records" mean in your application? Unless you provide some meaningful information, you're likely to have this question closed.

Comment: records as in rows in a table from the database. in this case each record consists of 12 fields.  I've instrumented the sporc to verify what the database is sending, ran break points to confirm the data gets to the model. checked windows event log, done several tests with varying number of records being returned, ran the app on both the "local" IIS express and on the a

Comment: It probably best to edit your question to include the information in your comment. You should also explain what the 502.3 errors means and why you think the MVC application is/is not responsible for causing the error. I did a quick check and it's basic an IIS level error thrown for a timeout.